# Undefined declaration result, when the original object and set variable have values

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman

I'm using node.js and Postman to POST to the function `/test`.  I store the field results into `toChange` and

> want to set: toChange.transaction.signature = element.transaction.signature;

The `toChange` variable has values, the `element.transaction.signature` has values. However, when I define `toChange.transaction` or `toChange.transaction.signature`, the declarations return `undefined`. Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

---

(the used section, in server.js):

```
logServer.post('/test', (req,res) => {
    console.log('starting test');
    let assetID = req.jwtPayload.assetID;
    logDB.collection('logs').find({"transaction.assetID" : assetID}).toArray( (err, result) => {

        if(err){
            console.log("Err : "+err.message);
            db.close();
            respondWithJSON(500,500,err.message,res);
            return; 
        }

        result.forEach(function(element, index, array) {

        let toChange = result.filter(function(e){return e._id === element._id});  //**HERE
        console.log('toChange', toChange);
        console.log('element.transaction.signature', element.transaction.signature);
        console.log('element.transactionSignature', element.transactionSignature);
        console.log('toChange.transaction', toChange.transaction); //**HERE

        //toChange.transaction.signature = element.transaction.signature; //**HERE
        //console.log('toChange.transaction.signature', toChange.transaction.signature);
        });
    });     
        res.status(200).send('hello, I am Log test');
});
```

---

(console.log output):

```
[stdout] starting test
[stdout] toChange [ { _id: 1511359949,
[stdout]     transaction: 
[stdout]      { actor: 'patman',
[stdout]        type: 'Upload',
[stdout]        assetName: 'benten40.txt',
[stdout]        assetOwner: 'patman',
[stdout]        signature: 'c7ac2d40-c41c-4cd6-88ed-51c309114f40',
[stdout]        timeStamp: '2017-11-22T14:12:29.000Z',
[stdout]        result: 'Success' },
[stdout]     transactionSignature: '632e61b5-a022-482c-a4c5-4940b53cb922' } ]
[stdout] element.transaction.signature c7ac2d40-c41c-4cd6-88ed-51c309114f40
[stdout] element.transactionSignature 632e61b5-a022-482c-a4c5-4940b53cb922
[stdout] toChange.transaction undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array, so you should do `toChange[ 0 ].transaction`. However, if you only want one element, use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Further, `_id` is likely an object of type [`ObjectID`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html). The equality operator for objects only returns true if they are the same object:

```
const obj1 = { a: 12 };
const obj2 = { a: 12 }; 
const obj3 = obj1;

obj1 === obj2; // false
obj1 === obj3; // true
```

You can either manually call `toString()` on both sides or use [`e._id.equals( element._id )`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#equals).

That being said, the `_id` objects *will* be the same object in this specific example, as both `e` and `element` come from `results` and `_id` is unique. `e` and `element` will also be the same object.